# Turn off auto complete /auto correct on Lync on Mac

Tags: macos, lync, microsoft-office

We use Microsoft Lync as the chat application in my work place. Recently we migrated to using macs and I am seeing this problem which i didn't see on the windows version of lync which was the auto correction which is extremely annoying sometimes.

Does anyone how to turn off this auto correct feature on mac version of lync?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

1. Open up a chat window. It doesn't matter which one.
2. Right-click in the text input field. *Spelling and Grammar*.
3. Toggle *Correct Spelling Automatically*.

This appears to turn the option off for all chat windows.

Tested on Lync 14.0.4 for Mac.

[image]

Comment: Awesome precisely what i was looking for.

Comment: if i open a new instance it seems to persist again.

Comment: nvm it worked yay!

Comment: Great place for a settings menu..with all the other settings.

Comment: Lync for mac is how MS punishes mac users

Comment: Nice solution for this It resolved my issue.

Comment: Thanks, this was very useful hint. It's 2016 and MS still sucks in creating great UXs. Why is this not a preference under the general properties. Was looking for this everywhere.

Comment: "This appears to turn the option off for all chat windows." - yes: lol.